# Bedeutungen von "aufsetzen"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, english-to-german, german-to-english

Ich bin kein deutscher Muttersprachler. Als ich mir die Bedeutungen von "aufsetzen" angeschaut habe, habe ich bemerkt, dass context.reverso.net es in erster Linie als "set up" ins Englische übersetzt. Dies hat mich überrascht, denn ich habe ähnliche Bedeutungen dieses Wortes in keinem Wörterbuch gesehen. In Anbetracht einzelner Teile davon kann ich nur vermuten, dass diese Bedeutung eine Lehnübersetzung aus dem Englischen ist. Auf jeden Fall interessiere ich mich, wie verbreitet sie ist und ob sie so kürzlich aufgetaucht ist, dass man sie noch nicht in Wörterbücher hinzugefügt hat.

Comment: some context would go a long way. IMHO it's one of those words which can have *very* different translations depending on context.

Comment: @planetmaker "Sie können die Workshops wie echte eigene kleine Events aufsetzen", "Er möchte ein weltweit neues Radiokonzept aufsetzen", "Wir schauen uns kurz an, wie du eine Kampagne für jede Plattform aufsetzen kannst". Das sind Beispiele aus context.reverso.net, und in jedem wird "aufsetzen" als "set up" übersetzt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eine Bedeutung des Wortes ist, sich aus liegender in eine sitzende Position oder sich aus einer weiter zurückgelehnten Haltung in eine aufrechtere Position zu bringen.

> Wenn der Wecker klingelt setze ich mich im Bett auf.

Daneben gibt es eine weitere Bedeutung, nämlich, den Kopf mit einer Kopfbedeckung zu versehen:

> Wenn es regnet setze ich einen Hut auf.

Außerdem gibt es die Bedeutung (von der ich allerdings vermute, sie ist nicht im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum üblich) "etwas auf den Herd stellen und erhitzen":

> Für die Nudeln setze ich einen Topf mit Wasser auf.

Aus dem englischen "set up" wurde hingegen eine weitere Bedeutung durch Entlehnung gewonnen: Sofware installieren, konfigurieren oder beides. Man kann "seinen Rechner aufsetzen" (also Betriebssystem und/oder notwendige Applikationen installieren oder konfigurieren), man kann auch "einen Webserver aufsetzen" (das entsprechende Programm möglicherweise installieren aber auf jeden Fall die Konfiguration - das sogenannte "customizing" - vornehmen).

Diese Bedeutung, *installieren und/oder konfigurieren* , wird auch in weiterem Sinne für "etwas in die Wege leiten, organisieren" verwendet:

> Ich habe die Konferenz aufgesetzt.

Das kann soviel heißen wie: die Einladungen verschicken, den Ablauf festlegen, die organisatorische Vorarbeit leisten - oder auch nur den Anstoß zu allen diesen Dingen geben.

Comment: Vielen Dank, jetzt ist das klar!